# Improve the Performance of Full-Text Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two Full-Text Search Queries

Query 1:

```
Declare @KEYSEARCH nvarchar(4000)="string search here....".
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONTAINS(col1,@KEYSEARCH)
```

Time execute this query: 0.2 s

Query 2:

```
 Declare @KEYSEARCH nvarchar(4000)="string search here....".
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE (CONTAINS(col1,@KEYSEARCH) or @KEYSEARCH='%%')
```

Time execure this query: 11s

Why is the second query so much slower?

Comment: What do you mean by @KEYSEARCH='%%' ?

Comment: Could you do an EXPLAIN ? I mean : put this keyword in front of your query. You will be able to have valuable data for query optimization.

Comment: @prasanna I suspect the purpose there is to allow a special "wildcard" that matches everything and returns all rows.

Comment: (thanks Joel Coehoorn for explaining my bad answers)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I suspect the engine is not smart enough to know you're not doing something that might modify the @keysearch variable over the course of the query (eg: certain tricks to do aggregate string concatenation do this), and so it has to re-run the `='%%'` check for every row in the table. It may also invalidate the full text index.